# Ordering columns in Rails, cakephp style

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cakephp, pagination

CakePHP's built in pagination helpers automatically allow column ordering in the view. If you bake the view you get a link on each column to order it by that data.

Is there a way to get this functionality in Rails? The standard will paginate doesn't offer it, anyone know any good ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[searchlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic) makes column ordering dead simple, and plugs in cleanly with will_paginate.

Comment: Worked a treat. Have a bicky.